# Why doesn't this select id work?

Tags: jquery, mysql, select, alert

**UDPATE**

Jquery included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This is the entire script(s) that I have been trying between this post and another one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/** function remove_entry() {
var answer = confirm("Delete this entry?")
if (answer){
         alert('yo');
         var identity = $(".red").attr('id');
         alert(identity);
}
else{
        //do nothing
}
}
$(function() {
    $('.red').on('click', '.red', function() {
        var eId = this.id.replace(/^\D+/, '');//since IDs should not start with a number
        $.post(
            'delete.php',
            {
                id: eId
            },
            function(data) {
                if (data.ok) {//sending JSON responses are easier to debug and you can add to them later without breaking things
                    //remove row
                }
                else {
                    //display error message
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
$(function() {
    $(".red").click(function() { alert(this.id); });
});**/
/**$(document).on('.red',click(
function(){
alert(this.id);
})
);
$(function() {
    $(document).on('.red', click(function() { 
       alert('yo');
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
/**
$(function() {
    $(document).on('.red', 'click',function() { 
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});**/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.red', function() {
        alert($(this).attr(id));
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the php part

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'dbconnect.php');

$link = new mysqli("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entries";

if ($result = $link->query($query)) {


    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        if($row[0]==0){
        echo "There are no entries.";
        }else {
        $query2 = "SELECT id,saying,date,thumbs_up,comments FROM entries ORDER by ID ASC ";

if (($result = $link->query($query2))) {
    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

       echo 
       '<div class="container" align="center"">'.
       '<div class="entry-container" align="left">'.
       $row[1]." ".
       '</div>'.
       '<div class="x" align="center">'.
       '<button class="red" name="remove" id="'.$row[0].'">x'.
       '</button>'.
       '</div>'.
       '</div>'.
       '<br>'
       ;

    }
    }
        }
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();

}

?>
```

**OLDER POST**

This is the script part

```
$(function() {
    $(".red").click(function() { alert(this.id); });
});
```

I am outputting rows from a database and each row has a delete button, by clicking on the delete button, I need to get the id of the row in order to send it to a delete script to delete that particular row.

this is a button

```
'<button class="red" name="remove" id="'.$row[0].'">x'.'</button>'.
```

based on what you see, why can't I alert the selected id?

Is this wrong?

```
$(document).on('.red',click(
function(){
alert(this.id);
})
);
```

Comment: What does it show in the alert instead of the ID?

Comment: the click event is not fired, I just want to see "1" haha then from there I think I am okay.

Comment: did you check `$row[0].` returns a valid value? how does your table looks like after generated when you view the source in the browser?

Comment: the $row[0] echoes correctly  I have seen it be displayed.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about php, however I wonder how your html looks after you display the page in the browser, is it generated properly ? can you also share just a small part of it?

Comment: The content displays fine, the rows are outputted, the buttons are on the right, the page design is simple, the rows are on the left and when selected (in the future) subrows appear in the right panel. I'm not sure what to do, I will try some simple projects to get the hang of selecting. This seems so trivial, delete.

Comment: dont include a jquery librry twice

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate function

try

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.red',function() { 
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: wow first mistake, didn't reference jquery, still it doesn't work, I see a message that says "click is not defined"

Comment: @janicehoplin can you share whole code in the original post? I suspect there are still problems in including jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this. I'm not sure `.on` can be used with `document`? Use `'body'`. And as Tamil pointed out, your `on` syntax is messed up.

You want this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.red', function() {
        alert($(this).attr(id));
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you make of "id is not defined"

Comment: just as a note, `$(document)` can be used with `on`

Comment: @janicehoplin when you select elements using a jQuery method, jQuery wraps them up inside jQuery objects. `.id` is a property of an HTML element, but not of the jQuery wrapper. The jQuery version is `.attr('id')`. To get HTML elements from a jQuery set either use array notation (`$(this)[0].id`) or jQuery's `.get()` method.